# How do I set the order a foreach loop loops through a panel of controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a foreach loop that goes through a panel of controls:

```
foreach(MyControl control in MyPanel.Controls)
```

and adds the name of each checkbox control that's checked to a list:

```
if (control.Checked == true)
{
  MyList.Add(control.Name)
}
```

but it seems to jump all around the panel in the order it adds them to the list. How can I set the order it runs through the panel so that it adds the names of the controls that are checked to MyList in a specified order?

Comment: It's adding in the order of each control in the ControlsCollection. Which order do you want?

Comment: I want to be able to edit the order it adds them... how do I change it from adding control QQQ then control RRR to adding control RRR then control QQQ

Comment: The only way to do that is to delete them and re-add them to the designer in the order you want. The simpler option is to copy the controls to an array and sort by something, like the tab index or the `Tag` property.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the collection to an `IEnumerable<Control>` and use `OrderBy`:

```
foreach(MyControl control in MyPanel.Controls.Cast<Control>.OrderBy(c => c.Name))
{
    if (control.Checked == true)
    {
        MyList.Add(control.Name)
    }
}
```

Or sort the list after adding all of the names, since you're only storing the name in the list:

```
MyList.Sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to Create your list

```
var MyList = MyPanel.Controls.Cast<Control>.OrderBy(c => c.Name).Where(c=>c.Checked).ToList();
```

Comment: I started by liking this answer, then it dawned on me that the `Checked` property will only be valid for CheckBox objects, so casting to `Control` won't work. Also, you should filter before sorting. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var MyList = MyPanel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
              .Where(c => c.Checked)
              .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
              .ToList();
```

As you might see, I'm using `OfType` instead of `Cast` because Cast will throw if it can't cast to CheckBox, whereas `OfType` will only return objects that CAN be cast to the desired type.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

MyPanel.Controls return a ControlCollection. A ControlCollection implements the IList interface, so you can use LINQ to sort it.

Comment: Technically you can use LINQ to _query_ the list and store the ordered results in a separate list, it won't actually sort the source `IList`.